# Chrome and Firefox freeze when I begin typing

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-chrome, freeze

Last night, chrome began freezing whenever I tried to type anything. After a fresh reinstall the problem went away but it is back again this morning.

I installed Firefox as a substitute browser but it has the same problem. I cannot even get past the homepage because typing in the u r l bar freezes both programs.

Last night internet explorer froze once too, but it has not happened since. Disabling shock-wave does not have any affect on the problem. Because it is happening across multiple browsers, I do not believe it to be caused by any extensions I have installed on Chrome. I also tried running Chrome as a new user and the problem still occurred. I can open any apps or web sites that are on my homepage, but as soon as I try to type anything the program freezes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked for viruses? Checked task manager to see what is using resources when you have the problem?

Comment: I ran a virus check last night and it came up clean. I'm running a boot time scan now as well. The processes that are running when the freeze occurs are all normal. Chrome has more than ten individual processes running, with one or two of them approaching 100k memory usage. My understanding is that's normal though.

Comment: Another thing to look for is any child process of chrome that is not a chrome process.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I use Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode (the OS in safemode not the program)? Spyware can do this, so a search using malware-bytes may help.

Comment: After I ran my boot time scan and got rid of several PUP's, it seems to be working fine. If it lasts then I guess it was malware, if not then I'll try safe mode and let you know how it works.

Comment: You say «Last night...» Try a system restore (assuming you're under Windows)

Comment: This happens to me sometimes when I use Aero. Well, it's generally slower to type with Aero in fact... as in the letters will appear with a slight delay. Unlike Windows Classic, where everything is instant. Using the latest VGA drivers with a powerful CPU. (But heck, who needs Aero?)

Comment: @mschulze what did you run? Malware bytes to scan for malware?